# Can I run Spotify by pressing my F8 button instead of iTunes?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, itunes, keyboard, spotify

Is it possible to program the F8 key to run Spotify instead of iTunes?

Comment: By "run", do you mean "start the application" or "start to play the current track"?

Comment: I mean "start the application" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this, is to set Spotify to `Open at Login`.
As long as iTunes is not opened, Spotify will get priority when you hit any of the special keys.

Alternatively you can install a little helper tool. Try these instructions from the [Spotify Community Forum](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Mac/Set-Spotify-As-Default-Music-Player/td-p/1271279):

Download Bubo (https://github.com/jguice/mac-bt-headset-fix#beta-version) and move application to the Applications folder

Then go into your Mac System Preferences --> Users and Groups --> Login Items -->

- Remove Itunes Helper
- Add Bubo

Done!

Answer (score 0):

F8 does not start iTunes app in a regular way. It's a kind of intra-system shortcut for launching a privileged default music app in macOS, which always will be iTunes. You can set F8 for launching Spotify using Automator or third party apps, but then this key will lost its play/pause functionality.